# Convert Key-Pair from Python List of Dictionaries to JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file of a list of dictionaries that I am trying to extract one particular key and its value from each dictionary and write them to a file back into JSON format.

In my code currently, I am looping through the dictionaries and appending them together in a json file. I am manually creating the json format but the key-values are written as a string. I suspect it has something to do with my dump(s) function. But is there a more efficient way to directly convert my key-values from python dictionaries to json dictionaries?

Here is my current output:

```
{
    "text: red"            #returns a string
},
{
    "text: yellow"
},
{
    "text: blue"
}
```

This is my expected output:

```
{
    "text": "red"        #returns json formatted key-value pair
},
{
    "text": "yellow"
},
{
    "text": "blue"
}
```

My current code:

```
with open(join(dirname(__file__),'text.json')) as tone_json:
python_obj = json.load(tone_json)          #read file object into string
my_list = python_obj["data"]               #assign list name to string
for dictionary in my_list:                 #loop through dictionaries in list
    for key,value in dictionary.items():   #loop through key pairs in dictionaries
        if key == "text":
            with open('comments.json', 'a') as f:            #append each pair
                f.write("{\n") .                             #write key pair objects as json formatted stream to json file
                json.dump("{}: {}".format(key,value), f)     #format key-values
                f.write("\n},\n")
```

My current list of dictionaries as "text.json":

```
{ 
    "data": [
    {
    "text": "red",
    "created_time": "2017-12-05",
    "comment_count": 31,
    "like_count": 43,
    "id": "10155952999xxxxx"
    },
    {
    "text": "yellow",
    "created_time": "2017-09-09",
    "comment_count": 4,
    "like_count": 876,
    "id": "10155952999xxxxxx"
    },
    {
    "text": "blue",
    "created_time": "2017-05-01",
    "comment_count": 15,
    "like_count": 6,
    "id": "10155952999xxxxxx"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking the solution.  You can shorten it to a simple list comprehesion:

```
with open(join(dirname(__file__),'text.json')) as tone_json:
    j = json.load(tone_json)
    out = [{'text': d.get('text', 'none')} for d in j.get('data', [])]

with open('comments.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(out, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: oh my goodness yes! this was it. i definitely overthought it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice when it comes to JSON, so I could be totally wrong...

But could a simple change in how quotations are implemented solve this issue with your current code?

```
json.dump('"{}": "{}"'.format(key,value), f)
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. I am learning too.